# Iterating with regex

Tags: php, regex, loops

I'm trying to loop until the desired string is found, but the script stops and doesn't loop. What's wrong here?

```
<?php

class foo {
    function somefunction() {
        $script =  dirname(__FILE__)."/script.sh";
        exec($script, $result);
        $result = array_map('trim', $result);

        $var1 = $result[2];
        $var2 = $result[4];

        $reg="/^String1/";

        if(preg_match($reg,$var2)) {
            return array('variable1'=>$var1, 'variable2'=>$var2);
            echo "<pre>\n";
        }

    else{
        while(!preg_match('/^String1/',$var2)) {
            $bar = new foo;
        }
    }
}
   } 
$bar=new foo;
print_r($bar->somefunction());

?>
```

Example of what I'm trying to achieve:

Loop:

1.Hi

2.Hello

3.String1(return this-regex match)

4.heyya

5.String1(return this-regex match)

Update: I had to increase xdebug.max_nesting_level else it returned an 'Maximum function nesting level' error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is that you're always finding a match with your first if statement:

```
if(preg_match($reg,$var2))
```

And then you return your function, so it never hits the while:

```
return array('variable1'=>$var1, 'variable2'=>$var2);
```

Since `preg_match` already returns an array of matches, you should be able to do something like this:

```
class foo {
    function somefunction() {
        $script =  dirname(__FILE__)."/script.sh";
        exec($script, $result);
        $result = array_map('trim', $result);

        $var1 = $result[2];
        $var2 = $result[4];

        $reg="/^String1/";

        if(preg_match($reg,$var2,$matches)) {
            return $matches;
        } else {
            $bar = new foo;
            return $bar->somefunction();
        }
    }
}
```

... only I'm still a little confused about where $var1 and $var2 come into play and why you're explicitly referencing the 2rd and 5th elements in that array?

Comment: I'm actually modifying this https://github.com/RobKohr/PHP-Bitcoin-Address-Creator

Comment: It returns false when the string doesn't match

Comment: Right - it would. I guess I can't see how calling a new instance of the class (like you did in the original while loop) would return different results? However, see update.